# MySQL: Order by newest datetime column?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, sql-order-by, inner-join

Here is the query before I added ordering:

```
SELECT `picture` 
FROM `profile_data` 
WHERE `profile_id` IN (
    SELECT `profile_id` FROM `collection_entries` WHERE `collection_id` = 2
) 
LIMIT 10;
```

I tried to add ordering like so:

```
SELECT `picture` 
FROM `profile_data` 
WHERE `profile_id` IN (
    SELECT `profile_id` 
    FROM `collection_entries` 
    WHERE `collection_id` = 2 
    ORDER BY `created_at` DESC
) 
LIMIT 10;
```

Although I receive this issue:

```
This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

Is there any way to do what I want to do?

Comment: There is no use for sorting in the `IN()` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join instead, so the `created_at` column is available in the outer query for sorting:

```
SELECT `picture` 
FROM `profile_data` pd
INNER JOIN `collection_entries` ce ON ce.`profile_id` = pd.`profile_id`
WHERE ce.`collection_id` = 2
ORDER BY ce.`created_at` DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

This assumes not more than one row in `collection_entries` for each `profile_data`. If that's not the case, then you need to pre-aggregate first. So:

```
SELECT `picture` 
FROM `profile_data` pd
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `profile_id`, MAX(`created_at`) `created_at`
    FROM `collection_entries` 
    WHERE `collection_id` = 2
    GROUP BY `profile_id`
) ce ON ce.`profile_id` = pd.`profile_id`
ORDER BY ce.`created_at` DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: I thought Gordon was the only SQL machine on this website.  I was wrong +1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I do take that as a compliment... Thanks!